# How to resize an image in Keynote or Pages?

Tags: macos, pages, keynote, image-editing

If I resize the width of an image in Keynote or Pages the height resizes as well. The same thing happens vice versa.

How can I resize the width without affecting the height and vice versa?

Comment: You mean cropping or stretching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the picture, then in the Arrange tab uncheck Constrain Proportions [you may have to revert to original size before that will un-grey.

Then dragging the image by any edge will stretch.

[image]

If you need to crop, that's in Image - Edit Mask [though crop doesn't constrain anyway]

[image]

Comment: Stretching should be forbidden ;)