# How can I resize an image within a table in Pages

Tags: pages

After adding an image (jpeg) to a table cell, I cannot resize it. The table is not locked, all arrange options are greyed out. If I triple click the image, it gets a blue bounding box but has no resize handles. I cannot resize the table cell itself; dragging a handle has no effect.

You can reproduce the problem by creating a new document based on the invoice template, inserting an image from Insert -> Choose into a selected table cell.

Pages version is 8.2.1 on MacOS 10.15.2

[image]

[This question does not help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193307/how-to-resize-an-image-in-keynote-or-pages)

Comment: Why put the image in a table cell at all? Why not just put the image on the canvas and prevent wrap? Perhaps for product description?

Comment: Why don't you paste the image outside the table first, resize it as you like and then paste it into the table?

Comment: Pasting the image somewhere else, then back into the table cell is a hacky workaround that shouldn't be needed. This feels like a bug.

Answer (score 4):

1. Double click on the image that is in the table.
2. Control-X to cut (and copy) it from the table.
3. Click anywhere outside of the table in the main body of the document
4. Control-V (or Command-V on a Mac) to paste it in the main body of the document
5. Grab one of the little handles on the corner of the image and resize
6. With the image still selected, Control-X to cut and copy the resized image.
7. Click (or double click) the destination cell.
8. Control-V (or Command-V on a Mac) to paste the resized image into the cell.
   Done.

Comment: My pleasure tiktuk...glad it worked for you! :)